# how to update the "Height map picture url" from a Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap in babylonjs

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, babylonjs

I'm new to babylon.js and try to build something with the function CreateGroundFromHeightMap. I would like to update the *Height Map url* parameter in babylon.js but i can't find how to do it.

here is my code to build it  :

```
var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap("ground", "textures/heightMap3.png",1000, 1000, 100,-100, 100, scene, false);
```

Should I completely delete my ground instance and load a new one or is there another solution? in the case of removing it, should I use only: ground.dispose ()?

Thanks of your replies

Comment: Another idea could be using .setEnabled() but i don’t know if it a good solution.

Thanks for your help,
Pierre (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to "update" the image used to create the mesh.

The mesh's geometry is created after downloading the image, and the image is then disposed and not being used anymore. The only way to create a kind of "update" mechanism is to dispose the old mesh and create a new mesh after downloading a new image.

Notice also that the function CreateGroundFromHeightMap is async. you can add an "onSuccess" callback to disable the old mesh and show the new one:

```js
let groundMesh;

function updateGroundMesh(newUrl, onSuccess) {
    if(groundMesh) groundMesh.dispose();
    groundMesh = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap("ground", newUrl ,1000, 1000, 100,-100, 100, scene, false, onSuccess);
}

updateGroundMesh("image1.jpg", () => {
    updateGroundMesh("image2,jpg");
});
```

This is of course a very naive approach, and will only update once) with a few frames in between to load the 2nd image). It requires improvements :-)